# Compute $\displaystyle\iint\limits_R\frac{y}{x+y^2}dA$ where $R=[0,1]\times[1,2]$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute $\displaystyle\iint\limits_R\frac{y}{x+y^2}dA$ where $R=[0,1]\times[1,2]$

$\displaystyle \int_1^2\int_0^1\frac {y}{x+y^2}dxdy=\int_1^2y(\ln|x+y^2|)\Big|_0^1dy=\int_1^2(y\ln|1+y^2|-2y\ln|y|)dy=\Big(\frac {(y^2+1)\ln(y^2+1)-y^2-1}{2}-2(\frac {y^2\ln(y)}{2}-\frac {y^2}{4})\Big)\Big|_1^2=\frac {5\ln(5)-10\ln(2)}{2}$

I got this answer with help from online integral calculator, but I don't really understand why $$\int_1^2(y\ln|1+y^2|-2y\ln|y|)dy=\Big(\frac {(y^2+1)\ln(y^2+1)-y^2-1}{2}-2(\frac {y^2\ln(y)}{2}-\frac {y^2}{4})\Big)\Big|_1^2$$

Can someone explain this please! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can certainly drop the absolute value bars from each of the logarithms. To integrate $y \ln (1 + y^2)$, substitute $u = 1 + y^2$; then

$$\int \ln u du = u \ln u - u + c$$

can be easily shown after integration by parts. Likewise, $y \ln y$ can be integrated by parts.